# Issue with conditionals in logstash with fields from Kafka ----> FileBeat prospectors

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat

I have the following scenario:

FileBeat ---->  Kafka -----> Logstash -----> Elastic ----> Kibana

In Filebeat I have 2 prospectors the in YML file,,. and I add some fields to identify the log data.
But, the issue is: **in Logstash I haven't be able to validate this fields.**

The configuration files are:

**1. filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /opt/jboss/server.log*
  tags: ["log_server"]
  fields:
    environment: integracion
    log_type: log_server

  document_type: log_server
  fields_under_root: true


- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/todo1_apps/ebanTX.log*
  tags: ["log_eban"]
  fields:
    environment: integracion
    log_type: log_ebanking

  document_type: log_ebanking
  fields_under_root: true

output.kafka:
    enabled: true
    hosts: ["192.168.105.68:9092"]
    topic: "sve_logs"
    timeout: 30s
```

**2. logstash.conf**

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "192.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092"
    group_id => "sve_banistmo"
    topics => ["sve_logs"]
    decorate_events => true
    codec => "plain"
    }
  }

filter {
if [type] == "log_ebanking" {
    grok {
       patterns_dir => ["patterns/patterns"]
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}]%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_log}" }
        }
  }
}

output {
if [type] == "log_ebanking" {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["192.168.105.67:9200"]
        index => "sve-banistmo-ebanking-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
        stdout { codec => json}
  }
}
```

The problem is in the conditional **filter** and **output** section. I've tried with

```
@[metadata][type]
@metadata][type]
@metadata.type
metadata.type
[type]
```

With both the type and log_type variable.  Nothing works !! :S
If I don't put conditionals, the data flow without problem. I mean, is not a conection issue.

Please help me. I've reviewed all the information related, but in my case the conditional doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Dario R

Comment: When you don't add the conditional is there a field `type` with a value `log_ebanking` in the events?

Comment: Hi Will, Yes, this is an example of message in Logstash:

{"@timestamp":"2016-11-25T18:57:48.569Z","beat":{"hostname":"inrhas14","name":"inrhas14","version":"5.0.0"},"environment":"integracion","input_type":"log",**"log_type":"log_ebanking"**,"message":"2016-11-25 13:36:53,508 ERROR [http-192.168.105.79:10080-3] - USER_ID: NONE","offset":216302,"source":"/var/todo1_apps/SVE-BSMO/logs/ebankingTX.log","tags":["log_ebanking"],**"type":"log_ebanking"**}

Comment: Can you run your logstash pipeline with the `--debug` flag and provide the output?

Comment: Hi Val, this is a example of a line of the output debug. Please let me know if this is enough:
[2016-11-27T21:39:49,226][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2016-11-28T02:39:48.410Z, "kafka"=>{"consumer_group"=>"sve_banistmo", "partition"=>1, "offset"=>1997, "topic"=>"sve_logs", "key"=>nil}, "@version"=>"1", "message"=>"{\"@timestamp\":\"2016-11-28T02:39:26.987Z\",\"beat\":{\"hostname\":\"inrhas14\",\"name\":\"inrhas14\",\"version\":\"5.0.0\"},\"environment\":\"integracion\",\"input_type\":\"log\",\"log_type\":\"log_ebanking\",

Comment: This is the continuation of the previous message,:

\"message\":\"2016-11-27 19:44:28,988 INFO  [ServerService Thread Pool -- 52]\", \"offset\":581298,\"source\":\"/var/todo1_apps/SVE-BSMO/logs/ebankingTX.log\",\"tags\":[\"log_ebanking\"],\"type\":\"log_ebanking\"}"}}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the message from kafka is not decoded. Logstash will take the whole json message reported by filebeat as the message. 
You can add json filter to decode the json format message.

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

The fields will be decoded. The message field will be replaced with the real message, rather than the whole json string.

Then you can use [type] in your conditional blocks. 
And the @metadata is not reported by filebeat when using kafka as output. So you cannot see @metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Use `codec => "json"` to extract all fields from the message in `logstash.conf` kafka input conf.

Answer (score 0):

Been through this before with Kafka!
Here are the steps I have done to make it work:

1. Update your Kafka input plugin
    cd /usr/share/logstash/bin
    then ./logstash-plugin update logstash-input-kafka
2. In yout LS config file add this to your Kakfa input plugin `codec => "json"`
3. keep you filter empty for now, as first you need to make sure you are receving the data in JSON on Elasticsearch. If you have Kibana check there or run ES queries if you dont.
4. then you should be able to access any fields anywhere in your LS config files.

Now for your output I see you are adding "log_type" to your events in filebeat, then I would suggest in your LS output plugin you do `if "log_ebanking" == [log_type]`.

The field `[type]` is by default "logs" for filebeat and "metricsets" for metricbeat for all events.

Not sure what is your Filebeat version but look at this as `document_type` is deprecated in 5.5 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#filebeat-document-type

Answer (score 0):

You can access to a custom field this way :

```
  if [kafka][fields][log_type] == "nginx_access" {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
        match => { "message" => "%{nginx_access}" }
    }
  }
```